# I purchased & downloaded Mountain Lion, and then...nothing happened

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, install, macos

I purchased Mountain Lion through the App Store on my 10.7.5 MacBook Pro.

The download completed and I clicked through the prompts to choose an install location and agree to the terms.

I'm sorry to say I'm not sure what happened next as I shifted my attention to another computer.

I assumed the install process was running.

However, when I looked back at my MBP, I was back on the desktop with no sign of activity.

(It's conceivable that I clicked "cancel" by mistake -- I'm kind of tired/distracted/trying to juggle several things at once today.)

I went back to the App Store, looked under "purchases," and found Mountain Lion labelled as "downloaded" (as I would expect).

How can I restart the installation?

Can I go to the downloaded file and click on it? Where would I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your /Applications folder. After downloading Mountain Lion, the installer is placed there (entitled Install OS X Mountain Lion).

It will be deleted after installation, but should still be present on your machine if you have not upgraded yet.

Comment: As an aside, since you have multiple computers, it may be worth pointing out that before running the Install OS X Mountain Lion app, you can copy it to a separate drive or USB memory stick, etc.  This way, you can install it on all your computers without having to wait for it to download on each of them separately.

Answer (score 2):

Look for **Install OS X Mountain Lion** in the Launchpad or Spotlight. It looks like this:

[image: Install OS X Mountain Lion]